# D3js pie animation on load not working

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to use attrTween in d3 to animate a pie chart when the page is loaded but it's not working for me. I've used attrTween before to animate a change in data and it's worked fine but this time I want to 'grow' the pie chart when the page is loaded first but it's not behaving as expected and I'm not getting any information as to why this is. 
If I remove the line `.attrTween('d' arcTweenStart);` then everything works fine except of course it does not animate. If the line is left in then nothing is displayed and the `arcTweenStart` function is never entered. Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

```
function drawCharts()
{
    // Create the chart and bind the data to it and position it
    var pieChart = d3.select("#groupRisk").selectAll("svg")
        .data(dataSet) // Bind the data to the chart
        .enter().append("svg")
            .attr("id", "pie")
            .attr("width", w) // Set th width
            .attr("height", h) // Set the height
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")"); // Position the chart

    // Create the pie chart layout
    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function(d) { return d.count; })
        .sort(null); // Sort is set to null to allow for better looking tweens

    // Create "slices" for each data element
    var arcs = pieChart.selectAll("g.slice")
        .data(pie) // Bind the pie layout to the slices
        .attr("id", "arcs")
        .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "slice");

    // Create the graphics for each slice and colour them
    arcs.append("path")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .each(function(d) { this._current = d; })
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attrTween('d' arcTweenStart);

}

function arcTweenStart(b) 
{
    var start = 
    {
        startAngle: b.startAngle,
        endAngle: b.endAngle
    };
    var i = d3.interpolate(start, b);
    return function(t) 
    { 
        return arc(i(t)); 
    };
}
```

**EDIT:**
My data set looks like this:

```
var dataSet= 
[
    [
        { "label": "Green", "count": 40 }, 
        { "label": "Amber", "count": 50 },
        { "label": "Red", "count": 10 }
    ],
    [
        { "label": "Green", "count": 20 }, 
        { "label": "Amber", "count": 30 },
        { "label": "Red", "count": 50 }
    ],
    [
        { "label": "Green", "count": 50 }, 
        { "label": "Amber", "count": 20 },
        { "label": "Red", "count": 30 }
    ]
];
```

I have an array of data sets so I want to draw a chart for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show what your `dataSet` variable holds (*that would have really helped answer the question!*) but assuming your data looks like this:

```
var dataSet = [{
    count: 4
  }, {
    count: 5
  }, {
    count: 6
}];
```

You don't need to do the first bind/enter:

```
d3.select("#groupRisk").selectAll("svg")
    .data(dataSet) // Bind the data to the chart
    .enter()
    ...
```

This would give you a pie chart for each entry in the data.  Getting rid of that, your bind then becomes:

```
var arcs = pieChart.selectAll("g.slice")
    .data(pie(dataSet)) //<-- call pie with the dataSet
    .attr("id", "arcs")
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "slice");
```

But really to the heart of your question, your tween `var start`, has the same start/end angle as where you want to end.  So, you animate the same thing over and over again.  What I think you meant is:

```
function arcTweenStart(b) {
  var start = {
    startAngle: b.startAngle,
    endAngle: b.startAngle //<-- set end to start and adjust on each call
  };
  var i = d3.interpolate(start, b);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}
```

Oh, and one typo in there too:

```
.attrTween('d' arcTweenStart); //<-- comma missing between 'd' and arcTweenStart
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aikA8z2wATkNVvMeZNhw?p=preview).

Comment: Sorry @Mark I should have included the data set. The missing comma was the reason that nothing was displaying (I think I'm too used to IDE's giving me syntax error warnings) You were completely right about the start and end angles, I ended up changing them both to 0 so the chart 'grows' from nothing. Thanks for your help!